# Upload de arquivo PHP que passa dados para o MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload, file-upload

*Vai ser difícil explicar o que eu quero mas vou tentar resumir em 2 pequenos parágrafos.*

### **Vamos lá**

Tenho um script que passa os dados de arquivo `.CSV` e `.TXT` para o banco de dados `MYSQL`, porém ele só funciona quando eu mesmo coloco o nome do meu documento e o próprio documento hospedado junto com ele, ou seja tenho um arquivo `importar.csv` e `importar.php`, no `importar.php` precisa estar setado o arquivo `importar.csv`.

### **Mas o que quer fazer?**

Gostaria que ele funcionasse com upload de arquivo php, ou seja, a pessoa (qualquer pessoa) que tenha acesso a área de upload, envie o arquivo `.CSV`ou `.TXT`e ao invés do arquivo `importar.php` setar  o arquivo `importar.csv`, ele setar o arquivo do upload.

Caso não entenda, por favor deixe um comentário que eu explico melhor.

**E o `importar.php` como está?**

```
$tabela = "n_emails";
$arquivo = 'importar.csv';

$arq = fopen($arquivo,'r');

while(!feof($arq))
for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){
if ($conteudo = fgets($arq)){
    $ll++; // $ll 
    $linha = explode(';', $conteudo);// 
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela (ativo, email) VALUES ('$linha[0]', '$linha[1]')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$linha = array();
}
echo "quantidade de linhas importadas = ".$ll;
```

Espero que tenha passado todas as informações necessárias para o entendimento de todos, agradeço a ajuda ou a tentativa haha.

Comment: vc precisa criar um `form` com enctype, um input `file` e usa a função [move_upload_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: muito obrigado @rray não entendia muito, mas dei uma estudada e é bem simples ao final, agradeço

Comment: Legal, bom ver que está progredindo :D